# This syntax error isn't recognized

Tags: node.js

What happened in this case?

Why there is no error?

I took a screen shot and hope you help me to find out what happened.

I can't post image please check this [link](http://www.axgig.com/images/28970336913866876806.png) out :

[image]

Comment: It's waiting for more input. try typing a semi-colon for example;

Comment: @torazaburo I try it but nothing work. and i really wanna know why it is happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a syntax error, in the earlier version of node, this error was not shown.
I run on node 6. and I got

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at Object.exports.createScript (vm.js:47:10)
at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:255:25)
at bound (domain.js:280:14)
at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:477:10)
at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
at REPLServer.emit (events.js:188:7)
at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:232:10)
at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:574:8)
at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:851:14)
```

It's becaus of this statment is meaning less.

[same on git](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan/issues/358)

Comment: Thank you so much. I had forgotten this. :)